# Count total sessions by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global

I found this tutorial to count the amount of sessions on an aspx website:

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-Show-Session-Count-in-ASPNet-Web-Application-227.php

I am storing a `String` (for example a user id) in a Session upon a login:

```
Session["Teacher"] = "123ABC";
```

This tutorial is fine when you want to count all sessions, but when you use two different session names, for example: `Session["Teacher"]`, `Session["Student"]`, and you want to count those sessions separated by name, the tutorial will not meet your requirements.

What can I do to count the total Sessions by name? So I want to achieve to get a count for `Session["Teacher"]` and another count for `Session["Student"]`

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to count the amount of objects stored in a particular session? You should update your question to make it clearer what you're asking.

Comment: You are confusing sessions (each user gets some server memory) and session keys (that memory is represented by several keys, each with a data item in it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Session["Teacher"]` and `Session["Student"]` are mutually exclusive:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Session Count is intialized with 0.      
    Application["TeacherSessionCount"] = 0;
    Application["StudentSessionCount"] = 0;
}
```

Then, where you assign `Session["Teacher"]`:

```
...
Session["Teacher"] = "123ABC";
Application.Lock();

int countSession = (int)Application["TeacherSessionCount"];
Application["TeacherSessionCount"] = countSession + 1;

Application.UnLock();
...
```

and where you assign `Session["Student"]`:

```
...
Session["Teacher"] = "456XYZ";
Application.Lock();

int countSession = (int)Application["StudentSessionCount"];
Application["StudentSessionCount"] = countSession + 1;

Application.UnLock();
... 

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key = null;
    if (Session["Teacher"] != null)
      key = "TeacherSessionCount";
    else if (Session["Student"] != null)
      key = "StudentSessionCount";

    if (key != null)
    {
      Application.Lock();

      int countSession = (int)Application[key];
      Application[key] = countSession - 1;

      Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

Mind the limitations of `Session_OnEnd` event described in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)